# How to order an array of objects by a certain property in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have an array of custom objects. The custom class looks like this

```
Person
-------
name
number
```

Now let's say I want to rearrange the array of these objects so that the objects are sorted by the number. How can this be done?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, it is not a programming language / library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** you have to implement following methods in your `Person` class

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForSorting {
  return self.number;
}

- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)person {
    return [[self numberForSorting] compare:[person numberForSorting]];
}
```

**2)** When a Person array is need to be sort you just call
a) in case of `NSMutableArray`

```
[peopleMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

b) in case of `NSArray`

```
NSArray *sortedPeople = [peopleArray sortedArrayUsingSelector@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: This is almost the correct answer.  in the numberForSorting method you would return the NSNumber representation of self.number, not self.name.